# Google Cloud ML Engine pass multiple file paths as arguments

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I am trying to run a job on Google Cloud ML Engine and can't seem to pass multiple file paths as arguments to the parser. 
Here is what I am writing in the terminal:

```
JOB_NAME=my_job_name
BUCKET_NAME=my_bucket_name
OUTPUT_PATH=gs://$BUCKET_NAME/$JOB_NAME
DATA_PATH=gs://$BUCKET_NAME/my_data_directory
REGION=us-east1

gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
    --job-dir $OUTPUT_PATH \
    --runtime-version 1.2 \
    --module-name trainer.task \
    --package-path trainer/ \
    --region $REGION \
    -- \
    --file-path "${DATA_PATH}/*" \
    --num-epochs 10
```

Where `my_data_directory` contains multiple files I later want to read, the problem is that `--file-path` contains only `['gs://my_bucket_name/my_data_directory']` and not a list of files in said directory.

How do I fix this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the arguments you pass after the `-- \` line will be user arguments, how the program handles these arguments will largely depend on the trainer you defined. I would go back and modify the trainer program and make it either treat the directory differently or take multiple paths like this:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
    --job-dir $OUTPUT_PATH \
    --runtime-version 1.2 \
    --module-name trainer.task \
    --package-path trainer/ \
    --region $REGION \
    --scale-tier STANDARD_1 \
    -- \
    --train-files $TRAIN_DATA \
    --eval-files $EVAL_DATA \
    --train-steps 1000 \
    --verbosity DEBUG  \
    --eval-steps 100
```

Some links that will be helpful for developing your own trainer: [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tutorials/samples) [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/concepts/trainer-considerations)

Comment: Yes, I ended up passing the directory of the files and then getting the files from within my program. It's just from the sample example, I was led to believe that I could pass multiple file names in one user argument, even though in the sample example they just use one file name.